# Disable/Enable audio on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, audio

I want to enable audio at `section#employee-dance`.
If the user scrolls out this element, audio will pause.

Currently, I only apply the code when user scroll to top, audio will pause.
Scroll down to next element, audio still play.

You can see my code and example at here:

```js
// Scrool div anchor
var targetOffset = $("#employee").offset().top;
$('#employee-dance').hide();
 var myAudio  = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() >= targetOffset) { 
        setTimeout(

           function(){
             
              $('#employee').replaceWith($('#employee-dance'));
              $('#employee-dance').fadeIn(2000);
              if($('#employee-dance').is(':visible')){

                myAudio.play();
                myAudio.volume = 0.2;
                $(".music-node").css('display','block');
              }
             
           },
           500
        );

    }
    else{
       myAudio.pause();
        $(".music-node").css('display','none'); 
        myAudio.volume = 0;
    }

});
```

```css
#top-text, #employee-dance, #down-text, #employee {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta dolor aspernatur reiciendis voluptates enim natus distinctio aliquid. Aut quaerat adipisci nam numquam alias suscipit, consectetur eveniet eius culpa quia explicabo!</section>
<hr>
<section id="employee">
</section>
<section id="employee-dance">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi pariatur nulla delectus dolores. Dolores veniam rerum consequuntur, odit repellendus. Suscipit hic tempore magni ducimus cupiditate adipisci, repellat illum laboriosam eius?
  <div class="raido-employee">
    <audio loop id="myAudio">
        <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div class="music-node"></div>
 </section>
<hr>
<section id="down-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa error, aspernatur eius labore recusandae beatae, sapiente, ad id impedit facilis qui debitis similique maxime perspiciatis atque quas dolore, nihil harum.</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Scrool div anchor
var danceEl = $("#employee-dance");
var danceElOffset = danceEl.offset().top;
var danceElHeight = danceEl.height();
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");

var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($w.scrollTop() >= danceElOffset && $w.scrollTop() <= (danceElOffset + danceElHeight)) {
    myAudio.play();
    myAudio.volume = 0.2;
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
    myAudio.volume = 0;
  }

});
```

```css
#employee,
#employee-dance,
#down-text {
  height: 700px;
}
#employee {
  background: green;
}
#employee-dance {
  background: red;
}
#down-text {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="employee"></section>
<section id="employee-dance">
  <audio loop id="myAudio">
    <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</section>
<section id="down-text"></section>
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your help.